# XAML binding issues with connected comboboxes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, reactiveui

I have two comboboxes: Categories and Types.  When my form is initially displayed, I am listing all categories and types that exist in the database.  For both comboboxes, I manually insert row 0 to be of value “All” so that they don’t have to choose either if they don’t want to.

I have both comboboxes bound to ReactiveObjects so that if the user selects a Category, the Types combobox is automatically re-populated with a query to show only types relevant to the selected Category along with the row 0 added.

When the user selects a Category, it runs the query properly, returns the relevant Types, adds the row 0 properly and the combobox is populated correctly; however, on the XAML size it’s not selecting the row 0, and it adds the red outline around the combobox signifying an invalid selection was made.

If no choice is made for the Type combobox and the form is submitted, the correct value of 0 is passed.  So while everything is working properly, the red box around the Types combobox is communicating to the user that they did something wrong and I cannot determine why the XAML isn’t picking up the selected values.  I have run the code without it adding the row 0 and it still has the same behavior, i.e., the combobox is populated correctly, but no row is selected and the red outline appears.

**XAML for comboboxes**

```
<ComboBox 
    Grid.Row="3" 
    Grid.Column="1" 
    Width="200" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top"
    Style="{StaticResource SimpleComboBox}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}"
    SelectedValue="{Binding SearchCriteria.CategoryID}"
    SelectedValuePath="ComboValueID"
    DisplayMemberPath="ComboDataValue"
    />

<TextBlock 
    Grid.Row="3" 
    Grid.Column="2" 
    Style="{StaticResource NormalTextNarrow}" 
    Text="Type" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
    />

<ComboBox 
    Grid.Row="3" 
    Grid.Column="3" 
    Width="200" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top"
    Style="{StaticResource SimpleComboBox}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Types}"
    SelectedValue="{Binding SearchCriteria.TypeId}"
    SelectedValuePath="ComboValueID"
    DisplayMemberPath="ComboDataValue"
    />
```

**Relevant VM code**

```
// Definition of SearchCriteria.  ResourceItem is a ReactiveObject and 
// all of the relevant properties watch for changes in values.
private ResourceItem searchCriteria;
public ResourceItem SearchCriteria
{
    get { return searchCriteria; }
    set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref searchCriteria, value); }
}

// This all happens in my constructor

// Defining Row 0
var b = new GenericCombobox { ComboValueID = 0, ComboDataValue = "All" };

// Populating the comboboxes from the database
Categories = omr.GetKTValues("RES_CATEGORIES");
Types = omr.GetKTValuesRU("RES_TYPES");

// Adding the row 0    
Categories.Insert(0, b);
Types.Insert(0, b);

// The form is displayed correctly at this point with the row 0 selected
```

**Problem Code**

```
// When the user picks a category, this is the method that is invoked:
private void categoryChanged()
{
    if (SearchCriteria.CategoryID != 0)
    {
        Types = rr.GetCategoryTypes(SearchCriteria.CategoryID);
        SearchCriteria.TypeId = 0;
    }
}

// This runs correctly and returns the relevant Types
public List<GenericCombobox> GetCategoryTypes(int categoryId)
{
    string sql = "res.usp_GetCategoryTypes";
    var types = new List<GenericCombobox>();

    SqlConnection sqlCn = DatabaseCommunication.OpenConnection();

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, sqlCn))
    {
        // Omitting db stuff for brevity...
        try
        {
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                types.Add(new GenericCombobox
                {
                    ComboValueID = (int)dr["TypeId"],
                    ComboDataValue = (string)dr["Type"],
                    IsSelected = false,
                    Description = (string)dr["Type"],
                    ComboDataCode = (string)dr["Type"]
                });
            }
            // More db-stuff omitted
        }

        // Adding the row 0
        var b = new GenericCombobox { ComboValueID = 0, ComboDataValue = "All", IsSelected = false, Description = "All", ComboDataCode = "All" };
        types.Insert(0, b);

        return types;
    }
```

**Update with Additional Code**

```
// Object containing the TypeId property
public class ResourceItem : ReactiveObject, ISelectable
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? OriginalItemId { get; set; }

    // ...many other properties...

    private int typeId;
    public int TypeId
    {
        get { return typeId; }
        set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref typeId, value); }
    }

    // ...and many more follow...
```

Comment: If i see correctly, you set the `Types` property to an empty list in categoryChanged, right before `Types` is assigned yet another list (returned by rr.GetCategoryTypes). Why do you do that? And how do you think the combobox reacts when it gets this empty list passed through the binding?

Comment: @elgonzo: tbh, it is just the result of my trying (and failing) at different solutions.  It's not necessary for anything else in my code and it has the same behavior if I take it out.

Comment: What if you re-set the SearchCriteria.TypeId property to 0 or whatever value to be selected after you have re-populated the Types property?

Comment: When you replace `Types`, that repopulates the Type combobox. The SelectedValue of that combobox is bound to something called `SearchCriteria.TypeId`. What that is, I can only guess, but it appears that the combobox is telling you that none of the items now in the combobox has a `ComboValueID` value equal to `SearchCriteria.TypeId`. And while I was typing that, mm8 said the same thing.

Comment: @mm8: I have tried that, too (not in the code I posted).  I can see in the debugger that it's set to 0,but it's not reflected in the XAML.

Comment: Do you raise the PropertyChanged event from the setter of the TypeId property?

Comment: @EdPlunkett: The combobox is bound to an object that has a `ComboValueID int` property.  It displays properly on the initial load using the same method to populate from the database.

Comment: @bassrek So it all works. Then why are you asking the question?

Comment: @mm8: Yes, well it's a ReactiveObject,so it I raise the `RaiseAndSetIfChanged` method for the property.

Comment: @EdPlunkett: All of the C# appears to be working, but it's not being reflected in the XAML.  The Type combobox becomes unselected and it gets the dreaded red outline as though something invalid was selected.

Comment: @bassrek In the case when it works, what is the value of `SearchCriteria.TypeId`? In the case when you get the red outline, what is the value of `SearchCriteria.TypeId`? Find out. Red outline is not the problem. This is not a "red outline" problem. The red outline is a *symptom*. it is *telling you that there is an invalid value*. Something in the C# is wrong.

Comment: Please show us the code for the `TypeId` property and the code where you update it after updating `Types`.

Comment: @EdPlunkett  `SearchCriteria` is of type `ResourceItem` and I've added the relevant code to the end of my post.  I've also updated my `categoryChanged()` code in the post to show how I have it currently setting `SearchCriteria.TypeId`.  I understand what you're saying and I know I'm missing something between the C# and XAML.  I've put watches on everything and I can see that before it leaves my VM `SearchCriteria.TypeId` = 0 and that the Combobox is bound to the correct property.  I don't know where else to look at this point.

Comment: @EdPlunkett: If I set my Row 0 ID to seemingly anything other than 0, it works correctly.  So right now I have it setting ComboValueID = 1 and SearchCriteria.TypeId = 1 and it all behaves as expected.  But if I set back to 0, it acts as though it cannot find the value.  I've not encountered something like this before.

Comment: @bassrek I've been able to reproduce the issue. Here's a funny thing: If I select an item in Types other than "All", then when I change the selection in Category, it selects "All" in Types. Another funny thing: It also works if, in `categoryChanged()`, I replace `SearchCriteria` with `SearchCriteria = new ResourceItem() { TypeId = 0, CategoryID = 0 };`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been able to reproduce the issue, and I've found a few silly things I can do that make it stop happening.

1. If I select an item in Types other than "All", then when I change the selection in Category, it selects "All" in Types.
2. It also works if, in `categoryChanged()`, I replace this line...

   ```
   SearchCriteria.TypeId = 0;
   ```

   with this one:

   ```
   SearchCriteria = new ResourceItem() { 
       TypeId = 0, 
       CategoryID = SearchCriteria.CategoryID 
   };
   ```
3. If I have `ResourceItem.TypeId.set` raise `PropertyChanged` regardless of whether the value has changed or not, it again works correctly.

My hypothesis is that the `SelectedItem` in the Types combobox (which you aren't even using!) is not changing when the collection changes, because you're not telling it to update `SelectedValue`.

Setting `SearchCriteria.TypeId = 0` is a no-op when `SearchCriteria.TypeId` is already equal to zero, because `RaiseAndSetIfChanged()` does just what the name says: It checks to see if the value really changed, and if it hasn't, it doesn't raise `PropertyChanged`.

`SelectedValue` happens by chance to be the same value as the new "All" item has, but the combobox doesn't care. It just knows that nobody told it to go find a new `SelectedItem`, and the old one it has is no good any more because it's not in `ItemsSource`.

So this works too:

```
private void categoryChanged()
{
    if (SearchCriteria.CategoryID != 0)
    {
        Types = rr.GetCategoryTypes(SearchCriteria.CategoryID);

        SearchCriteria.SelectedType = Types.FirstOrDefault();

        //SearchCriteria.TypeId = 0;
        //SearchCriteria = new ResourceItem() { TypeId = 0, CategoryID = SearchCriteria.CategoryID };
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<ComboBox 
    Grid.Row="3" 
    Grid.Column="3" 
    Width="200" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Types}"
    SelectedValue="{Binding SearchCriteria.TypeId}"

    SelectedItem="{Binding SearchCriteria.SelectedType}"

    SelectedValuePath="ComboValueID"
    DisplayMemberPath="ComboDataValue"
    />
```

class ResourceItem

```
private GenericCombobox selectedType;
public GenericCombobox SelectedType
{
    get { return selectedType; }
    set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref selectedType, value); }
}
```

I think your best bet is my option #2 above:

```
private void categoryChanged()
{
    if (SearchCriteria.CategoryID != 0)
    {
        Types = rr.GetCategoryTypes(SearchCriteria.CategoryID);

        SearchCriteria = new ResourceItem() {
            TypeId = 0,
            CategoryID = SearchCriteria.CategoryID
        };

        //  Do you need to do this?
        //  SearchCriteria.PropertyChanged += SearchCriteria_PropertyChanged;
    }
}
```

The potential problem here is that, in my testing code I called `categoryChanged()` from a `PropertyChanged` handler on `SearchCriteria`. If I create a new `SearchCriteria`, I need to make sure I handle that event on the new one.

Given that, maybe binding `SelectedItem` on the Types combobox is the best solution after all: It's the only one I can think of that doesn't require the viewmodel to do strange things to make up for misbehavior in the view that it really shouldn't be aware of.

Comment: Recreating the SearchCriteria object is problematic because I have many other properties on this view that I left out for brevity sake.  But your note: `Setting SearchCriteria.TypeId = 0 is a no-op when SearchCriteria.TypeId is already equal to zero...` is the key.  Thanks so much for going through the effort of reproducing.

Comment: @bassrek Yeah, the more I thought about recreating `SearchCriteria`, the more I got a sinking feeling that it was not going to be a good idea for you.